# Is the Standing Wave of a particle Hologram "interactive"?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, diffraction, wave-particle-duality, hologram

In other words, suppose one creates a particle hologram -- no photo reaction, just a standing waveform in space. Suppose the particle is something we are skilled at manipulating, like an electron.

Next, one continuously blasts the kind of energy the particle would normally absorb at the hologram.

Will the particle, when it is finally detected at some terminating point (like a phosphorous plate) have the same, more, or less "energy"?

And, as a follow on, would there be any mechanism to do this (interact with the diffracted particle), under any conditions?

---

In short: you can **absorb** energy from diffractions to **record** a hologram. Can you push energy **into** the system?

---

**Disclaimer**: I recently asked a question on this topic, and discovered that, *yes*, particle holograms exist:

[Matter Holograms: What would be involved?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/601933/157259)

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a *particle hologram*? A *hologram* is a virtual image created by a diffraction plate, and it's hard to see what the phrase would mean when applied to an electron.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/601933/157259

Comment: @JohnRennie just posted a disclaimer: I have reason to believe particle holograms do in fact exist, and all the way up to carbon-60 buckyballs.  I asked that question on here a few days ago.

Comment: What that describes is not a *hologram of a particle*, it is a holographic image (presumably of some macroscopic object) made *with particles*. The electrons (or whatever) passing through the diffraction plate are just electrons, like the photons creating a hologram are just photons. All you are doing is changing the probability of detecting the particles at any particular point in space.

Comment: @JohnRennie yes exactly: can you interact with those probabilities as if they are the particle?  For example, as I understand it, the **definition** of a particle is the high likelihood component of its probability distribution function.  And, when you create a hologram, you create a large standing volume of the particle's pdf, just **waiting** for large wavelength, low energy interaction and manipulation, no?

Comment: The probability $Ψ^*Ψ$for one electron to exist at a specific (x,y,z,t) is a solution of the quantum mechanical  equation  given the boundary conditions.The distribution appears when a large number of electrons follow the same boundary conditions. Each electron is on its own particle track . See the double slit one electron at a time to understand that the wave is a probability wave, individual electrons are individual points on the screen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles

Comment: @annav yes, however the entire point of the double slit experiment, and the hologram, is that the electron is able to interfere with itself, and is therefore **not** on a single electron path in an energy minimizing hamiltonian without violating the a-priori probability distributions a-posteriori (after observing the collision spot).   So, it is fine, in my humble opinion, to process the collision event as an instantaneous collapse of the probability distribution, rather than evidence of some squiggly particle path..or evidence that the apriori cumulative path probabilities were wrong.

Comment: @annav in other words, if you were to emit in-phase electron waves such that, just prior to a collision spot there was a local minimum of likelihood...and just at the collision spot a local maximum, the electron collisions observed really would comply with the probability peaks and troughs as you moved your phosphorous plate. Thus, a hologram is possible.  If the electron tunneled to achieve this, it would exceed the speed of light... or have a winding and/or fast and slow path through the intervening space. Further, it could not self-interfere if it flew like a bullet.

Comment: @annav in my opinion, having a particle that meanders through the probability soup as a self contained particle on a grinding path through space implies a *much* more complicated particle, and a lot more information the universe has to "know about" for the particle to move through space.   This seems energy intensive for the light and breezy electron. But if, on the other hand, the particle really does spread out as a fluid probability wave and interfere with itself, you in fact have *much simpler*, *self evident* behavior.   The universe has to remember nothing.

Comment: **"electron is able to interfere with itself, " ** this is wrong. Every electron is a little dot, a footprint of a particle,and the electrons in the experiments have simple tracks,they are not spread all over.. It is the accumulation that has  wave characteristics. see the electrons here https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm .  Particles do not self interfere, sorry.

Comment: @annav this drives diametrically against everything I know about modern quantum mechanics.  I'll have to check with the head of my local physics department on that one -- a former bell labs researcher and theoretical physicist specializing in quantum mechanics and optics. And quite a good soccer player.

Comment: @annav and yes, prior to diffraction, electrons are self contained -- like bullets.  Hence the stupendous puzzle of the double slit experiment.

Comment: @annav It also doesn't mesh well with Feynman's lectures (that nobel winner), existing accepted questions on here, or regular photon holograms (which require the phenomenon we know as noise cancellation to actually work -- the photon has to penetrate through a medium designed to absorb photons without being absorbed... if the photon is actually a self interfering wave, then this is plenty possible; if it is a particle, it will simply register at the surface of the solid hologram film)

Comment: There are no popes in physics. Only experimental numbers and mathematical models. Difraction offers boundary conditions and a new wave function for the photon or any particle appears, a **new probability** distribution. It is not a classical phenomenon at the level of a single photon, probabilities are not .interactive.. Single photons would behave the same way as with the double slit I linked, adding up to the classical diffraction pattern in accumulation.

Comment: @annav that seems like something there should be an experiment for to rule out.  Since, as you claim, there are "no popes in physics"  (I beg to disagree: I think physics is filled with popes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I'll answer the question I *think* you want to ask: "*If an unspecified kind of particle is diffracted by a standing wave pattern formed by a particle beam, how is the particle affected?*"

The experiment you describe probably has never been done using electron beams to form a standing wave.  However, an inverse of the experiment has been done: Light has been used to form a standing wave pattern, and particles have been diffracted by that pattern.  Perhaps more to the point, sound waves have been used to form a standing wave pattern, and light has been diffracted by that acoustic standing wave.  See [Acousto-Optic Modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optic_modulator).

When light is diffracted by the acoustic standing wave, it does indeed pick up (or lose) energy. Similarly, it is reasonable to expect that a standing wave produced by interfering particle waves would add (or subtract) energy from light or matter waves diffracted by the standing wave.

Comment: "Perhaps more to the point," 

Comment: And what I am driving at next is: suppose you have a certain type of particle or amalgam (like a nucleus) that can absorb only energy which is packed tight enough to "interact" with the particle or amalgam (ie, you can only make a 1000 nm wavelength, but your target is 10nm, let's say).  Then, would it not be possible to add energy to your target particle by interacting with the diffraction or standing wave of that particle (which is much larger).   I'd like to ask it as a standalone question... but, right off the bat, do you think it is off base?

Comment: I hesitate to answer because I don't really understand what you're reaching for.  Would you like to continue in Chat?

Comment: yeah -- that would be awesome

Comment: If I can figure out this chat feature anyways.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/117545/holography?tab=general  -- alright, I created this room.   And, as far as what I am driving at, well, I acquired some 40 year old paper compendiums that chronicled the rise of lasers and holography from the basics all the way to the 1980s and the laser disc from a retired professor's book dump across the hall a few years back.  And I flipped through and read a good chunk of them.  Then, I started watching this guy, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-421-atomic-and-optical-physics-i-spring-2014/video-lectures/lecture-1-resonance-i/

Comment: To be honest, I am not really sure what I am driving at; more or less I am trying to unpack what I've been learning in a way that makes sense to me, and clear the content that I think is junk out of my brain -- I am not on the physics PhD track, and I am no longer in R&D, so I'm trying to figure things out for myself.